# anime.js - how do I combine animations with different timings?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I would like to apply 2 different anime.js animations on an element.
But only the last one is applied.

https://plnkr.co/edit/p5fRlznLA98056SxDmIh?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  anime({
    targets: ".box",
    duration: 2000,
    loop: true,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    direction: 'alternate',
    translateX: 250
  });
  anime({
    targets: ".box",
    duration: 1000,
    loop: true,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    direction: 'alternate',
    scale: 0.5
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge both animations into one, but the `alternate` direction can't be applied to specific properties.
But you can use keyframes to achieve a similar effect :

```
  anime({
    targets: ".box",
    translateX: 250,
    scale: [
      {value: .5},
      {value: 1}
    ],
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'easeInOutSine',
    direction: 'alternate',
    loop: true
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't seem to work: https://plnkr.co/edit/YQEeZTU4pkRUA66TuT3L?p=preview
The box's size should oscillate while the box moves.

Comment: `direction` is set to the whole animation, and can't be specified to a single property. But you can achieve a similar using keyframes. I updated the code example to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, Julian. Your updated code works. https://plnkr.co/edit/x5hPeXBWmuOZOqogJuce?p=preview